# DMax function not working when MS Access is not open

Tags: database, vba, excel, ms-access

I am writing a code in VBA that allows for a new user to be added in the database using a user form in MS Excel. The database must be automatically updated once the form is submitted. I am using the `DMax` function to get the highest existing primary key in the table. I then increment it to get the primary key for the new user to be added. The code works perfectly when the database is open in MS Access. However, it returns the error "Sub or Function not defined." whenever MS Access is not open.
Here is the code that is highlighted when the error appears:

```
userID = DMax("[UserID]", "subscriber_user") + 1
```

`userID` is my variable, `UserID` is the column containing the primary keys, and `subscriber_user` is the name of the table in the database.

Is it necessary for the database to be open using MS Access for it to work? Is there another method to make sure that the database gets updated without having it to open it via MS Access or any other IDE?

Comment: You should be using DAO/ADO to update the data, in which case you can get the ID using a SELECT query. Not really sure why you need to get the PK though.

Comment: @Rory I am updating the data using an SQL query and it works just fine. My only problem is the DMax function. I'm new to all this and I'm not sure how auto-increment should work here so I get the PK of the latest record so I can increment it using the code then pass it in the query where I insert the new record into the table.

Comment: Isn't your PK an autonumber? If it is, you don't need to include it when you add the data.

Comment: @Rory I'm not the one who created the database so I'm not really sure but I'm looking into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMax for a database is an Access VBA function, not an Excel VBA function.

You'll need to either connect via DAO/ADO, or create an Access object like this:

```
Public Sub AccessDmax()

    Dim userID as Integer
    Dim oAccess As Object
    Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    oAccess.Visible = False
    oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\test_databases\test.accdb"

    userID = oAccess.DMax("ID", "subscriber_user")

    oAccess.Quit
    Set oAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! I'm still confused as to which functions are under Access and which ones are under Excel. Thank you very much for this.